# Unable to Backup Data restored to Google Drive via "Backups" Application. Please help to get my data RESTORED

Tags: backup, notification, restore, google-drive, 23.04

When I got to know that **Ubuntu 23.04** was out, I wanted to *try* it. I don't know why but previously while I was using **Ubuntu 22.04 LTS**, I had opted to get *notifications* for ***future releases of builds***, but I could only get **Upgrade notifications** to **22.10** and not to **23.04**. So I thought of **manually upgrading** to **23.04** by **clean-install** (***erasing all data***). To **PRESERVE** my **Data**, I used **"Backups" *Application*** to ***restore*** all my **Data** to **Google Drive** without any *difficulty* as my ***GDrive*** has ***large storage***. *But now*, after ***installing*** **23.04**, as I'm trying to **restore back my Data**, the ***Application*** is giving me a *notification* as shown *below*.

[image: The Image of ERROR]

Please HELP me bypass this error and get my Data restored.

Comment: Please do help or I would lost a significant amount of Data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have not already tried this, [several others with the same issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/deja-dup/+bug/1847196) seemed to be helped by installing PyDrive as the error message implies:

```
sudo pip3 install PyDrive
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, but when I tried this command in Terminal, it shows this error - 

"sudo: pip3: command not found".

How to resolve this one! @johnandmegh

Comment: The first Google hit for that message would indicate that you would then need to install the python3-pip package: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48014769/pip3-command-not-found